# Excel macro generates Subscript out of Range error

Tags: vba, excel, do-while

All three sheets will have the same column headings in row 1. On the first and second sheets in the workbook (titled "Monthly" and "Annual" respectively), I am using conditional formatting to color cells in columns Y and AC  based upon there values as determined by a formula (Yellow if the calculation returns a value less than 90, Red if the value returned is 0 or a negative number). What I would like a macro to do is to copy the entire row from column A through column AD to a third sheet (titled "Maint Due"). It would also be nice if this process were automated so that anytime the values in columns Y and AC changed in the "Monthly" or "Annual" sheets, the information in the "Maint Due" sheet was automatically updated (but if I have to rerun the macro manually for that to happen it's not a big deal).

I've never used the Macro recorder and I can only figure out how to create a macro to copy and paste, so I had no luck there. After doing some more searching and watching some videos I cobbled this together:

```
Sub Show_on_Maint()
x = 2
'Sets the starting row

    Do While Cells(x, 2) <> ""
    'Continue to evaluate until a blank cell is reached
    If Cells(x, 25) <= 90 Then
        'Evaluates the cell in column Y to determine if the value 
        '     is less than or equal to 90
        Sheets("Monthly").Rows(x).Copy Sheets("Maint Due").Range("A2")
        'Copies the row to the Maint Due sheet
    Else
        If Cells(x, 29) <= 90 Then
            'Evaluates the cell in column AC to determine if the value 
            '     is less than or equal to 90
            Sheets("Monthly").Rows(x).Copy Sheets("Maint Due").Range("A2")
            'Copies the row to the Maint Due sheet
        End If
    End If
    x = x + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

When I run/debug it I get a Loop without Do error. I think my logic is sound but I don't have enough experience to figure out why I'm getting that error.

EDIT: Fixed the missing End If before x = x + 1

Now I receive a runtime error 9 "Subscript out of range" at: `Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).Copy Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A2")`

EDIT: Fixed sheet names. Macro now runs without errors but doesn't appear to do anything. Also edited main post for brevity.

Comment: Missing `End If` just before `x = x + 1`

Comment: Are you sure you have sheets with those names?

Comment: Could you please narrow down your question to just essential part and specify the problematic part? Thanks and regards,

Comment: I don't see Sheet1 and Sheet6 n your code where these names have came from, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

You code snippet contains multiple error. The first 'Loop without Do error' has been fixed in comments. The second one, 'Subscript out of range' is self-descriptive, so check the maximum value of `x+1` by adding

```
Debug.Print x = x + 1
```

to your loop. Also, make sure that you are not referencing a non-existing Worksheet (i.e. `Sheets("Sheet6"`)) in your copy statement.

Hope this will help.